# How to do the equivalent of SELECT .. FRO UPDATE in a SOA architecture?

Tags: web-services, oracle, transactions, locking, odp.net

The title is probably not be explicit enough, so let me try to explain. I'm working on a new project, built on .NET, it consists of WPF clients that use WCF web services to access an Oracle database. The problem is not this basic architecture, but rather how it's supposed to work with what's already in place.

Currently, applications are written using PowerBuilder and connect to the database directly. Additionally, they use Oracle's `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` statements extensively to manage concurrency by locking records. Since the new applications must exists side-by-side with the old ones, they are supposed to lock records in a similar manner too, but the new architecture that relies on web services does not make this easy.

For the moment, what we are thinking of doing is build a "data server" that would be called by the web services and would be responsible for accessing the database. The purpose of this server is to maintain the open connections/transaction needed to maintain record locks throughout several web service calls. This is needed because the "select" and the subsequent "update" parts of the operations that require `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` are most likely going to happen in at least two separate web service calls ("get record" and "post update".)

I've searched the Internet for documentation regarding this kind of situation, but I can't seem to find much on the subject. Can this—i.e. keep record locks open throughout several web services calls—be done? Properly? Is my approach appropriate? Are there any published "best practices" on the matter?

**Update:** The original title of the question was *How to maintain record locking with a service oriented architecture?* I changed it following John's suggestion, hoping it may inspire some answers.

Comment: PS. I apologize in advance to the site's moderators if this question is not appropriate for SO (maybe not specific enough). If it has to be closed, or moved somewhere else, I'll understand. To other visitors, if you need more details, I'll gladly provide them.

Comment: You really should ask a question that is more specific. For instance, maybe narrow it down to "how to do the equivalent of select for update in a SOA architecture.

Comment: You might want to have a look at shared server and drcp.

Answer (score 0):

In general the SOA already have XA transaction turned on.  So you can benefit from this and use the UPDATE / SELECT / UPDATE strategy.  Meaning that say, you do UPDATE/SELECT as a single INVOKE example is:

- UPDATE MY_TABLE SET state='Working' ... ;
- SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE state='Working' ...

Then you can process the data with out fear of someone else will claim that data since it already in a different 'state', provided that the service you write only one in existing for each table.

Finally, you can complete it with the UPDATE ... SET ... state='Complete' where state='Working'.  By the way, this is the same strategy the DatabaseAdapter use for polling.